# actionscript 3 error 1136: incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

when i call a method i get the 1136 error and it says that I need 1 argument, but I didn't request any parameters:

```
function tutorial()
{
main.arcade.gotoAndStop(5);
gotoAndPlay(2);
Main();
}
```

here is the class I am calling

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    var temp:int;
    var temp2:int;
    var onLeft:Boolean = true;
    var coolDown:int;
    var distance:int;
    var p2h= new hitBar2();
    var p1h= new hitBar();
    var roy = new Roy();
    var shane = new Shane();

    public function Main(){
        combat(roy,shane);

    }
```

I am quite new to actionscript and programming in general, please help!!!

Comment: The error is easy to solve, however if you could post the error you're getting as a whole (everything in output) that will provide extremely useful information such as which method you're calling that is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a constructor like

```
Main();
```

Try

```
var main:Main = new Main();
```

Also if the Main class is you applications main class (the entry point) then you can do something like the following.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
    var temp:int;
    var temp2:int;
    var onLeft:Boolean = true;
    var coolDown:int;
    var distance:int;
    var p2h= new hitBar2();
    var p1h= new hitBar();
    var roy = new Roy();
    var shane = new Shane();

    public function Main()
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init():void
    {
       removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
       combat(roy,shane);
    }

    private function combat(roy:Roy,shane:Shane):void
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am still getting errors but I think I can figure them out by my self.